# Vec3b does not take three arguments?

Tags: opencv

Im using classes to create a function. The function must find a selected colour in the image provided. So I made it so that the function takes a Vec3b value since it is an RGB value we are talking about.

```
class colorcompare
{
private:
int threshold;
Vec3b color;

void setcolor(Vec3b);
Mat process(Mat&);
void setthresh(const int);
int getdist(Vec3b);
};

void colorcompare::setcolor(Vec3b colr)
{
color = colr;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

colorcompare cc1;
Mat image;

image = imread("c:\\car2.jpg", -1);

cc1.setcolor(19,69,139); //This is where im getting error
cc1.setthresh(100);
namedWindow("meh");

imshow("meh", cc1.process(image));
waitKey(0);



return 0;
}
```

Now the error I am getting is this: `'colorcompare::setcolor' : function does not take 3 arguments`

I know that vec3b is a vector of 3 values, so in other words I can access the individual values of vec3b as color[0], color[1] and color[2].

And I know I can define it like such in the function above but it shouldnt the vec3b be able to take 3 values? Like I did in my code?

Comment: I forgot to mention that ``setcolor(19,69,139)`` is the BGR value for brown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Classic mistake: **the function expects a `cv::Vec3b` object, not 3 `int` variables**.

If you want a single line solution, try this:

```
cc1.setcolor(cv::Vec3b(19,69,139));
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined setColor to take a Vec3b as parameter, so you should give it a Vec3b:

```
cv::Vec3b color(19,69,139); // or cv::Vec3b color; color[0]=19, ...
cc1.setColor(color);
```